# Bluetooth module not working

Tags: hc-05

I was following a tutorial on YouTube to build a Bluetooth car with Arduino.

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

//initial motors pin
AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ); 
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR34_1KHZ);

char command; 

void setup() 
{       
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Set the baud rate to your Bluetooth module.
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){ 
    command = Serial.read(); 
    stop(); //initialize with motors stoped
    //Change pin mode only if new command is different from previous.   
    //Serial.println(command);
    switch(command){
    case 'F':  
      forward();
      break;
    case 'B':  
       back();
      break;
    case 'L':  
      left();
      break;
    case 'R':
      right();
      break;
    case 'S':
      stop();
      break;
    }
  } 
}

void forward()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(255);//Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
}

void back()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
}

void left()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(FORWARD);  //rotate the motor clockwise
}

void right()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwiseclockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
} 

void stop()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(0); //Define minimum velocity
  motor1.run(RELEASE); //stop the motor when release the buttonbutton
  motor4.setSpeed(0); //Define minimum velocity
  motor4.run(RELEASE); //stop the motor when release the button
}
```

Here's the schematic:

[image: Image of the Arduino bluetooth control robot schematic]

I didn't use the resistor, I used 4 aa batteries, and I used 2 motors instead of 4, but the bluetooth module is flashing.

Comment: Please include the image directly into your question.

Comment: Could you establish the bluetooth connection to the HC-05 on your smartphone? Did you configure the module to use 9600 baud for the serial connection?

Comment: ok i will one second

Comment: @chrisl i don't understand, but yes i established the bluetooth connection to the hc05 on my smartphone but i don't understand the second part

Comment: The HC-05 is a bluetooth-Serial bridge. The pins going to TX and RX of the Arduino are for the Serial (UART) communication interface. For using that interface, both devices need to be configured to the same baudrate/speed. In your sketch you are using 9600 baud. But often the HC-05 modules are configured for something like 38400 baud by default. So have you made sure, that you are using the same baudrate in your code as the HC-05 uses?

Comment: yes i set the serial.begin to 38400

Comment: but it is still not working

Comment: `I didn't use the resistor`...  so ... you wired the bluetooth module direct to the Arduino with no logic level translation?

Comment: no i used the arduinon driver board

Comment: and the hc05 module has a 3.3v regulator

Comment: @powerdido2007 Most HC-05 modules only have a 3.3V regulator for the power lines. They don't translate the data lines. Thus the 5V from the Arduino at the HC-05s RX line can damage it

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: generally with the HC-05 it isn't plug&play. Please google for some tutorials about it and try them first. It can be rather complex, so that answering here for all possible problems is too much.